# Extracting numbers preceding a word

Tags: text-processing

Say I have a programme that outputs several lines, some of which contain
the word `messages` preceded by a number.  How could I extract only those
numbers?
(And how could I output only their sum?)

Comment: it would have been better if you'd added a sample text and expected output along with what you tried yourself to solve this problem..

Comment: @Sundeep, why exactly?

Comment: giving an example helps to test solutions as well as adds clarity.. for ex: are there multiple occurrences of `messages` in a line? is the number integer/float, etc... and it is expected to add research effort while asking a question.. I've often seen such questions receiving downvotes (there's even a reason given if you hover on the downvote button) and getting closed.. you were lucky in this case to get such a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using `grep`:**

```
grep -Po "[0-9]+(?= messages)"
```

---

**Explanation**:

- `-P`: Use perl-regex (PCRE)
- `-o`: output only the match instead of the matching line.
- `[0-9]+` match digits.
- `(?= messages)` match only if *" messages"* follows (= *positive lookahead*).

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`, and assuming those are decimal integer numbers with optional whitespace between the number and `messages`:

```
cmd | awk '
  match($0, /[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*messages/) {
    sum += substr($0, RSTART)
  }
  END {print 0+sum}'
```

With `perl`:

```
cmd | perl -lne '$s += $1 if /(\d+)\s*messages/; END{print 0+$s}'
```